# how can I see only the specific range of cells(named range) from excel data that can match the criteria equal to the name range?

Tags: excel

for example: an excel spreadsheet for a year, i would like to see only a specific quarter data and not the entire data. All quarters are named. and a dropdown list that can simlify the selection.

Comment: Use `Aggregate()` function with combination of `Index()` function with date.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Why not use the `Excel filter` function on the column that the quarters are in? Also you might want to look into `pivottables`